# Vertex Dark Theme doesn't look good in VMware Workstation 11.1.3

Tags: gnome, themes, vmware-workstation

I am using Vertex Dark Theme in Ubuntu 14.04.4 64 bit and I just love this theme. But it looks weird in VMware Workstation 11.1.3.

[image: Image of Workstation GUI]

Is this an Ubuntu issue or a theme issue?

Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: Not using that theme is a workaround.  VMware not working with certain themes would be a VMware software issue; they don't particularly give attention to those types of bugs.

Comment: Try using the default Ubuntu themes and see how they behave. This is likely a VMware issue

Comment: Default themes works perfectly:-) Thanks for your time and reply!

Answer (score 1):

Launch it with `export VMWARE_USE_SHIPPED_GTK=force vmware` and you can continue to use your dark theme and vmware will use the inbuilt Gtk theme.  UPDATED:  Please see VMWare Workstation 14 Update for GTK3+.

Comment: I will do that. But I have to upgrade to VMWare Workstation 14 first;-)